# GC content of a protein-coding region

Tags: dna, bioinformatics

I have computer science background and I am trying to understand the equation below.

**The average value of the G + C content of a protein-coding region is
given by :**

(G+C)=  $\sum_{\alpha} (I_\alpha *f _\alpha$ )/3

$I_\alpha$ = Maximum number of nucleotides C and G that appear in one of the
synonomous codons for given amino acid

$f_\alpha$ = Frequency of amino acid α.

Where does the 3 in the denominator come from ?

Answer (score 4):

[Each codon codes for one amino acid and every codon contains 3 nucleotides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_code).